# Added a modified file in git index but the file is not changing to staged

Tags: c, git, libgit2

I'm trying to add a file to index to create a commit with libgit2.

The repo and index are like that:

```
git_repository *repo;
git_index *my_repo_index;
git_repository_open(&repo, ".");
git_repository_index(&my_repo_index, repo);
git_index_add_bypath(my_repo_index,"a.txt");
//all functions are returning 0, or success.
```

The "a.txt" file already exists in the index and is a modified file.

Before the commit the file is under "Changes not staged for commit", and I thought that after that the file would be under "staged" like after I executed "git add a.txt" but that didn't happened.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changes to the index are not immediately written to disk.  You might, for example, wish to perform a number of actions and save them all at once.  In order to save the index:

```
git_index_write(my_repo_index);
```

Comment: Or you might not want the index to ever make it to the disk, e.g. if you're committing some auto-generated docs into a branch.